# Some point in a line $Ax+By+C=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Given a line in a 2D space, defined by equation $Ax+By+C=0$, is it possible to find a point of it without assume that A or B are different of 0 ?

That is, usually the method to find some point is "assume $A \ne 0$, if we fix $y=0$ the solution of the equation gives that point $(-C/A,0)$ is a point of the line, **otherwise** $B \ne 0$ and ...·

But it is possible any other method without split the problem in two ?

In other words, is it possible to find an expression for some point (any one) of the line that doesn't contains a division by A, B or C or by any other term that can be zero in some cases ?

The question could be expressed in another way: given a line $Ax+By+C=0$, give an expression of the same line in vector/parametric form that is valid for any value of A, B, C.

The direction vector is easy to find, (-B,A), the remainder target is to find the expression of some point.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand precisely your point, could you better explain please?

Comment: @gimusi: clarified in the question (and thanks for asking instead of close vote)

Comment: you are welcome, the implicit cartesian form is the more general to define line equation (the explicit doesn't work for vertical line), as an alternative you can use parametric equation.

Comment: thus the problem is: I have Ax+By+C=0 and you want to find a point?

Comment: @gimusi: yes, the expression of a point, any one. But an expression that doesn' t assume nothing about A,B,C values (except that A and B can not be 0 at same time).

Comment: Why number of close vote still increasing ? no duplicate, no off-topic and, if someone needs more clarifications, just place a comment to allow improve the question.

Comment: I'll flag this to the moderators.

Comment: @gimusi: open discussion in meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308272/294022

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the additional line $Bx-Ay=0$. The linear system
\begin{cases}
Ax+By=-C\\[4px]
Bx-Ay=0
\end{cases}
has solution
$$
x=-\frac{AC}{A^2+B^2}
\qquad
y=-\frac{BC}{A^2+B^2}
$$

### Comments

The additional line is the perpendicular passing through the origin and we found the intersection of the two lines. If $C=0$, we of course get $(0,0)$, but no assumption on $C$ is actually necessary.

Since either $A$ or $B$ is nonzero, we have $A^2+B^2\ne0$, so the division doesn't pose problems.

A graphic example with $A=3$, $B=2$, $C=5$ that shows we're essentially finding the point having minimal distance from the origin.

[image]

If instead you consider as additional line $Bx-Ay=t$, for a variable $t$, the solution is
$$
x=-\frac{AC-Bt}{A^2+B^2}
\qquad
y=-\frac{BC+At}{A^2+B^2}
$$
and, as $t$ varies, you get *all* points on the given line.

Comment: You are assuming C=0, this is not a general expression of a point for any line defined as Ax+By+C=0. Moreover, see previous  Ethan answer.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui No, this is correct. If you substitute those values in your equation you do get $Ax + By +C = 0$, for any value of $C$.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: Given that the final solution explicitly contains $C$, it is quite obviously *not* assumed that $C=0$. Note that the line $Bx-Ay=0$ is a *different* line (that is perpendicular to the original one).

Comment: Sorry, my confusion, though first statement was line equation

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Sorry: had to post the answer before the battery of the tablet died. I added a few comments now. Please, remove the comment to the accepted answer about being the first: it wasn't. I'm not begging for the check mark, I'm more satisfied to have written something that *teaches* how to get the solution.

Comment: :-) battery always dies in worst moments, they have a sensor. If I understand, this point is at the cross of the line with a perpendicular that pass by (0,0), and its modulus is the distance minimal from line to (0,0)

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Yes, that's what it is.

Comment: As generalization of this method, if a rotation $\alpha \neq 0, 180º$ is applied to $(A,B)$, the second line becomes $(A cos \alpha - B sin \alpha ) x + ( A sin \alpha + B cos \alpha ) y = 0$ with solution $(x,y)=(\frac{-ACsin\alpha-BCcos\alpha}{(A^2+B^2)sin\alpha},\frac{-ACcos\alpha-BCsin\alpha}{(A^2+B^2)sin\alpha})$. This is another way of express all line points, being the point given in this answer the particular case for $\alpha=90º$.

Answer (score 3):

How about
$$( -\frac{AC}{A^2 + B^2}, - \frac{BC}{A^2 + B^2})$$

Comment: The particular case $C=-1$ is useful

Answer (score 1):

For $C=0$, we can choose

- $x=-B$
- $y=A$

For $C\neq0$ and $A=1$, we can choose

- $x=-C-By$

For $C\neq0$ and $B=1$, we can choose

- $y=-C-Ax$

For $C\neq0$ and $C=kA$, we can choose

- $x=-B-k$
- $y=A$

For $C\neq0$ and $C=kB$, we can choose

- $x=-B$
- $y=A-k$

otherwise we need always division.

Comment: But what two points will you use? Can you describe them in terms of $A$ and $B$ without division by either?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui maybe I didn't cacth the motivation of the OP :) The other alternative is the explicit form $y=mx+n$, what about it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the interesting open point is proof the statement "otherwise you need always division".

Comment: @pasabaporaqui ah ok, now is clear to me!

Comment: Probably I should clarify before that division by a term that can not be 0 in any case is valid

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Yes I didn't cacth your point at all till the final answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I think the answer is "no".

If $C = 0$ then the point 
$$
\left( \frac{AB^2}{A^2+B^2},  \frac{-A^2 B}{A^2+B^2} \right)
$$
will do, but if $A=0$ and $C \ne 0$ then $y$ must be $-C/B$. You have to divide by $B$. Any general formula you propose to deal with the general problem will have a $B$ in the denominator.

**Edit.** As @gimusi  points out, $(B, -A)$ works when $C=0$. My solution was clumsy.

**Edit.** My "think so" is wrong. Other answers are better. At least my use of $A^2 + B^2$ was on the right track. It's the determinant of the matrix in @egreg 's solution.